# Cloud9 - Local on DigitalOcean

Tags: cloud9-ide

i have been googling it for all day and i can't find anything that might give me a hint on this.
i have my server hosted on Digital Ocean. untill today i signed up for a free cloud9 account, and used ssh to connect to my server.
but i understand that i can actually clone the IDE and intall it locally on the server (even though it is kind of already installed). but i can't find any tutorial on how to access it later, i mean, lets say it is installed on the server, i need a way to ssh to that server dont i? so how can i interact with it?

i want it locally to be able to install plugins..

some light might help :)
thanks

Comment: Can you tell me a bit more about how you're installing it on your droplet? Are you installing https://github.com/c9/core?

Comment: for now i do it through cloud9.io and ssh from there. but i was wondering if i can install it on droplet

Comment: You could do it by downloading and installing from the repo I gave the link to, but it's not exactly like c9.io

Comment: I installed github.com/c9/core but how do I access it on my droplet's IP it only runs on 127.0.0.1 ? thanks.